# deployment of shiny app fails due to cmake

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, rsconnect

I have a shiny app that uses `nloptr` , which in turns needs `cmake`. I installed it locally and everything works, when I try to publish it to an private rsconnect server, it fails with the following error:

`[Connect] 2022/12/06 14:24:08.680333733 CMake was not found on the PATH. Please install CMake: ...`

So it is clear that the compiler is missing, is there any solution besides asking the server admin to install cmake or a way for R to install it?